# How to change hostname in ateoas

Tags: spring-hateoas, hateoas

I am trying to modify the hostname for the links in Hateoas but it just doesnt look straight forward. Any thoughts on how I can modify this to replace the hostname?

```
HalModelBuilder builder = HalModelBuilder.halModelOf(resource)
        .link(linkTo(methodOn(BaseController.class).method1(...))
            .withSelfRel())
        .preview(new SummaryResource(...))
        .forLink(
            linkTo(
                methodOn(RefController.class).method2(...)
                .withRel("blah"));
```

**Update:**

I tried to achieve to replace the hostname with below code:

```
HalModelBuilder builder = HalModelBuilder.halModelOf(resource)
        .link(
            Link.of(
                apiGatewayUrl +
                    linkTo(methodOn(BaseController.class).method1(...)).toUri().getPath())
                .withSelfRel())
        .preview(new SummaryResource(...))
        .forLink(
            Link.of(
                apiGatewayUrl +
                    linkTo(methodOn(RefController.class).method2(...)).toUri().getPath())
                .withRel("blah"));
```

Tried using .toUricomponentBuilder() to replace hostname, but url building is not happening right. So chose to go with concatenating gatewayUrl with hateoas generated path.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you use Spring HATEOAS behind a gateway. If your gateway sets `x-forwarded-*` headers correctly and if you use Spring Boot, set a property `server.forward-headers-strategy = framework`, according to the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-behind-a-proxy-server). Then
[`ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.java) creates a `ForwardedHeaderFilter` bean for you.

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingFilterBean(ForwardedHeaderFilter.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "server.forward-headers-strategy", havingValue = "framework")
public FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    ForwardedHeaderFilter filter = new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR);
    registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return registration;
}
```

Then Spring HATEOAS generates links with the same base URI (hostname, port, path) as you saw it outside the gateway. See [Spring HATEOAS documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#server.link-builder.forwarded-headers).